# Angular Compilation Warnings after installing Angular Material

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular-material

when I trying to compile after installing [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) in my Angualr project, but project not working, i got a following error any one know how to fix that issue

[image]

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(214,21): error TS1039:
>   Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(4957,22): error TS1039:
>   Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
>   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(9664,36): error TS1254: A 'const'
>   initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal.
>   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(10335,55): error TS1254: A
>   'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric
>   literal. node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(11600,12): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'unknown'.
>   node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12116,12): error TS2304: Cannot
>   find name 'unknown'. node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12347,86):
>   error TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation
>   comments. node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(12347,86): error
>   TS8028: JSDoc '...' may only appear in the last parameter of a
>   signature. node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts(13684,120): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.

Comment: Did You install by command `ng add @angular/material` ?

Comment: @Mises Hi, yes i already flowing this https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started instruction

Comment: Ohh they change documentation before ppl were installing using NPM and not setting up.

Comment: If it is old project try to install older @angular/material version ?

Comment: @Mises Thanks i will try older version

Comment: home it will solve Your problem.